# How did California voters by age group vote in the 1984 U.S. Presidential Election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, data-sources, california, exit-polls

Is there information on how voters of different age groups in California voted in the 1984 election? For example, what percent of the 18-24 vote in California went to either Reagan or Mondale? Or voters aged 65 or over?

Comment: I suspect this is too detailed.  Polling was not as detailed in '84.  You can find national polling information, but exit polls of individual states seems unlikely.

Comment: Darn, it'd be pretty interesting to see that info if it were available. But I guess things were more limited back then.